# Segmentation error when trying to access element of a multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array and a one dimensional vector.
My task is to write a program, that assigns to the i-th component of the vector

1. the first element of the i-th row of the matrix, if there is at least one negative element in that row,
2. the last element of the i-th row, if there isn't.
   Here is what I've done.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
    
int main() {
    double matrix[4][4] = {{1.3, -5.0, 4.4, 3.0}, {7.0, 4.0, 2.01, 1.0}, {7.0, 12.3, -8.7, 9.0}, {4.0, 1.0, 33.0, 63.3}};
    
    double vector[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            bool rowHasNegNum = false;
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; i++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] < 0) {
                    rowHasNegNum = true;
                }
            }
            if(rowHasNegNum) {
                vector[i] = matrix[i][0];
            } else {
                vector[i] = matrix[i][3];
            }
    }
    

        
    for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        cout<<vector[i]<<"\t";
    }
    cout<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

But when I compile the program, I get the following error. What's the problem?

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: unrelated, but using `vector` as a variable name is a terrible idea.

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you so much, I corrected it and my program worked as expected :)

Comment: @M.A thanks for advice, indeed...

Comment: @M.A *strongly* disagreed. It can be an entirely appropriate variable name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph not when mixed with `using namespace std` :D

Comment: @M.A The issue in that case is unambiguously the `using namespace std`, not the use of a perfectly sensible name.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, good point, I agree. Might be jarring a large shared repo to alias names with STL container names, but with good practises in place, not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The fault is here `for (int j = 0; j < 4; i++)`. Your not incrementing `j`, instead your incrementing `i`. And since `j` is not getting incremented, `i` gets incremented passing the bounds of the array. This is the reason for the segmentation fault.

The fix is simple, just swap `i` with `j` here,

```cpp
for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 4; i++) {
```

You are incrementing the wrong variable here. A compiler warning picked this up, you should make sure you have warnings enabled.

And by incrementing `i` in this loop, you are accessing values outside the array resulting in the segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks, my program worked. How can I enable warnings? I'm using an online compiler

Comment: @ArmanGrigoryan depends on which you use, you should be able to set the compile flags somewhere where you can add `-Wall` which roughly stands for warnings all

Answer (score 3):

For starters neither declaration from this header

```
#include <cmath>
```

is used in the program. So remove it.

Do not use magic numbers like `4` or `3` in these statements

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)

ector[i] = matrix[i][3];
```

Instead use named constants.

In this for loop

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 4; i++) {
                       ^^^
```

there is a typo. You need to write

```
 for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                       ^^^
```

This for loop

```
        bool rowHasNegNum = false;
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (matrix[i][j] < 0) {
                rowHasNegNum = true;
            }
        }
```

should be interrupted as soon as a negative number is found.

Also instead of this for loop you could use the standard algorithm `std::any_of`.

In this case your program could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    double matrix[N][N] = 
    {
        { 1.3, -5.0,  4.4,  3.0 }, 
        { 7.0,  4.0,  2.01, 1.0 }, 
        { 7.0, 12.3, -8.7,  9.0 }, 
        { 4.0,  1.0, 33.0, 63.3 }
    };
    
    double vector[N];
    
    size_t i = 0;
    
    for ( const auto &row :matrix )
    {
        using std::placeholders::_1;
        if ( std::any_of( std::begin( row ), std::end( row ), 
                          std::bind( std::less<>( ), _1, 0 ) ) )
        {
            vector[i++] = row[0];
        }
        else
        {
            vector[i++] = row[N-1];
        }
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : vector )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1.3 1 7 63.3
```

If to use only loops then the program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const size_t N = 4;
    double matrix[N][N] = 
    {
        { 1.3, -5.0,  4.4,  3.0 }, 
        { 7.0,  4.0,  2.01, 1.0 }, 
        { 7.0, 12.3, -8.7,  9.0 }, 
        { 4.0,  1.0, 33.0, 63.3 }
    };
    
    double vector[N];
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        bool rowHasNegNum = false;  
        
        for ( size_t j = 0; not rowHasNegNum && j < N; j++ )
        {
            rowHasNegNum = matrix[i][j] < 0;
        }
        
        vector[i] = rowHasNegNum ? matrix[i][0] : matrix[i][N-1];       
    }
    
    for ( const auto &item : vector )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```